# Chisel3: Bitwise negation operator

Tags: chisel

There appears to be either a bug with or undocumented changes to the bitwise negation operator between chisel2 and chisel3.

Chisel3 code not working

```
import chisel3._

class bitwise_neg extends Module {
    val io = new Bundle {
        val in   = Input(UInt(4.W))
        val out  = Output(UInt(4.W))
    }
    io.out := ~io.in
}
```

Error message generated for line containing "~":

```
type mismatch; found : ()chisel3.core.Bits required: chisel3.core.Data
```

Chisel2 working code

```
import Chisel._

class bitwise_neg extends Module {
    val io = new Bundle {
        val in        = UInt(INPUT, 4)
        val out       = UInt(OUTPUT, 4)
    }

    io.out := ~io.in
}
```

Any ideas on the new Chisel3 syntax or if this is a bug?

Comment: The chisel3 code you provided should work, and I have no problem running your example (with 1 minor change, in chisel3 you need to wrap your io Bundle with `IO(...)`). Can you share more about your build environment?

Comment: I'm using Scala IDE on Windows. I used SBT to generate the Eclipse project using scalaVersion 2.11.8. and Chisel 3.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Works for me on MacOS with that scala version and Chisel 3 snapshot, I can't imagine how the IDE or Windows would make a difference here. Can you share the full error message and stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to the `~`, you will get the same error even if you remove the `~`.  Just as jkoenig said, **chisel3 requires that you wrap the io bundle in an IO()** like this:

```
class bitwise_neg extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in   = Input(UInt(4.W))
    val out  = Output(UInt(4.W))
  })
  io.out := ~io.in
}
```

If you want (but I wouldn't recommend it) you can use chisel2 notation using the compatibility layer in chisel3 with capital chisel `import import Chisel._`

```
import Chisel._

class bitwise_neg extends Module {
  val io = new Bundle {
    val in   = UInt(INPUT, 4.W)
    val out  = UInt(OUTPUT, 4.W)
  }
  io.out := io.in
}
```

Comment: I still get the same behavior with the IO() wrapper in place. Perhaps the issue lies with the Eclipse interpreter? Chisel3 produces this warning in Eclipse where I use ~                                                                         value unary_~ is not a member of ()chisel3.core.UInt